# Mssql Server looses connection to domain; cannot access any shares until reboot

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, broadcom

Server is Windows 2008R2.
MSSQl Server 2008 is installed.
4 Broadcom Network Cards (3 active, 1 standbye)

We had two time the same issue:

*Suddenly we cannot access any network shares on other servers.*

I'm seeing the following error in the eventlog:

```
The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the file  \\datacenter.xxx\SysVol\datacenter.xxx\Policies{D91EEC74-1A4B-42B6-B1B1-...}\gpt.ini from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy settings may not be applied until this event is resolved. This issue may be transient and could be caused by one or more of the following:
a) Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain controller.
b) File Replication Service Latency (a file created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller).
c) The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been disabled.
```

- Drivers and Firmware were upgraded after the first occurence. Switches were changed.
- I can ping all servers.
- DNS is working (tested with nslookup. short and fqdn).
- I've disabled all network cards and enabled them again.
- Network was recognised as "home" network. Don't know why. I've changed to "work". Domain was not detected. After rebooting the server the domain was recognized.
- I've checked other servers in the same network, I can see no problems.

So it seems to be specific to one server, but I have no clue how to solve the problem.
My current workaround: Rebooting the server. After rebooting everything seems to be ok.

Any ideas, what I can check now? I
What can I check as well if it happens again?

Answer (score 0):

The network location changing will definitely cause a problem.  You should be able to test/validate this by configuring the firewall profiles to off.

**The network location profile changes from "Domain" to "Public" in Windows Server 2008 R2**
https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2524478

Comment: Good Point! But I've forgot: Firewall is disabled for all profiles. So it should be possible to reach Domain Controller and network shares even with "public" profile, am I right?